Firefox - How can I change window/site minimum width or disable it to make it flexible?
I'm currently trying to switch browser from Chrome to Firefox. But currently, there is a problem with Firefox where the window/site width size is not as flexible as Chrome window/site width size. On chrome, I can make the site have width as small as possible without cutting the view, while in Firefox it just cuts at certain width.

The website width is currently being cut unlike on Chrome
I have tried multiple things such as using userChrome.css advice from multiple Firefox forum but it still doesn't work. I tried to look for default/full sample of userChrome.css file or the entire documentation that may show some pointers about site min-width but I still couldn't find it(You can share the full documentation link if possible, that will help me a lot).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Normally, the pages adjust to a minimum size because they are responsive. This issue is new to me unless you have changed something in the settings

what userchrome.css changes have you done?

@juliethefoxcoon Added chrome hidden toolbar to min-width 100px and also tried url bar min-width 100px, but it still stuck at that width. I'm looking for window/website min-width but couldn't find anything like that so far

@Z0OM I haven't change things too in settings and this was fresh firefox install. I'm still investigating this problem on my spare time

@Z0OM Yeah, you're right. The page size does adjust, it seems like it's the window size problem(as you can see, the button on the right side of toolbar got cut off)

did you try adjusting min-width for :root

@juliethefoxcoon Okay, now it's working as I intended with :root only (previously I tried :root:not([chromehidden~="toolbar"])), although the toolbar UI is broken but that's fine, Thank you... Do you want to add that as answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Add this to your userchrome.css:
/* userChrome.css */
:root {
    min-width: 1rem !important;
}

